# Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity() のリターン値の実体は？

Tags: php, zend-framework

前任者から引き継いだPHPコードをメンテナンスのために読み込みしています。

```
Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity();
```

のリターン値は下記URLで記述のように
getIdentity() - 認証を試みた ID 情報を返します。
http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/ja/zend.auth.introduction.html

これは例えばログインIDのような単なる文字列だと認識していますが、それで良いのでしょうか？

なぜこんな質問をするかというと現在読み込んでいるソースコードで

```
$user = Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity();
$user_id = $user["id"];
```

のような実装をしています。
$userを連想配列（ユーザオブジェクト）のように扱っているように見えます。

そのためZend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity() のリターン値が単なる文字列なのかオブジェクトを返すことができるのだろうか？
という質問です。

よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

アダプタ(`Zend_Auth_Adapter_***`)の実装によりけりで、文字列でも連想配列でも返すことができたと思います。

`Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable` だと文字列を返しますし、`Zend_Auth_Adapter_Http` だと連想配列を返します。

Comment: @ngyukiさん、回答ありがとうございました。
ソースをチェックしたところ、Zend_Auth_Adapter_Interfaceを実装した独自クラスを定義していました。
authenticate()でDBアクセスしてユーザオブジェクトを生成してZend_Auth_Resultとして返していました。
なのでリターン値が連想配列としてアクセスできる実装と判明しました。